# Is "have understanding" right to use? Or should it be replaced with "understand"?

Tags: british-english

Is "have understanding" right to use? Or should it be replaced with "understand"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help if you gave a sample sentence where you intend to use this word or words.

Comment: @KillingTime "I have good understanding of the Order Management module." When I used this, MS Word suggested me to use "I understand the Order Management module".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In everyday English it is most common to say “I understand politics” for example, but you can also say “I have a good/bad/excellent understanding of politics”. This is more typical in formal language (in a job interview, for example).

Comment: I corrected it to "I have good understanding" and it worked. Thanks.